# Reading a list of network printers from NTUSER.dat

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm trying to use Powershell to get a list of printer queues from a user's previous NTUSER.DAT file, so that we can script adding them back in. Just using the HKEY Current User to test. So far I have:

```
Get-Childitem -path HKCU:\Printers\Connections | Select Name
```

Doing this returns:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Connections\,,\\print_server\queue_name`

Since the queue names are stored in the Key name, is there an easy way to look at any subkey under Connections key, and add just the queue name to an array or variable, for use further into the script? There could be any number of printer connections

Answer (score 0):

Just added the * at the end of Connections. From there I was able to parse the string, and break it down to just the queue name.

Get-Item -path HKCU:\Printers\Connections* | Select -ExpandProperty PSChildName